# Angular 2 ngSwitch directive, same content

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a ngSwitch which changes the directive to what I need. Inside each case is exactly the same code (arround 100 lines).

```
<div [ngSwitch]="i + 1">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1" directive1> Same content, many divs, many ngFor.. </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="2" directive2> Same content, many divs, many ngFor.. </div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="3" directive3> Same content, many divs, many ngFor.. </div>                    
</div>
```

Works fine so far, but I have many unused code and changing simple things has to be done in all Cases (10 at the moment).

Is there a way to either use the same content in the cases or switch the directive definiton to a more comfortable way ?

I tried with exporting the Content to a custom component and import it there, but this leads to much problems (I have than arround 50 @Inputs and need a big service to communicate between parent and all the other sister and brother components)

Comment: Why would you do that if you have the same content everywhere?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Cause I need different directives to fire specific events based on the index "i". Eg. the elements out of loop 1 should be clickable, the elements out of loop 2 should be draggable and the ones out of loop 3 have a mouseover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update Angular 5**

`ngOutletContext` was renamed to `ngTemplateOutletContext`

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-beta5-2017-08-29

**original**

```ts
<ng-template #content let-items let-idx="index">
 Same content, many divs, many ngFor..
</ng-template>

<div [ngSwitch]="i + 1">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1" directive1><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content; context: {$implicit: myData, index: i}"></ng-container></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="2" directive2><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content; context: {$implicit: myData, index: i}"></ng-container></div>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="3" directive3><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content; context: {$implicit: myData, index: i}"></ng-container></div>                    
</div>
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgTemplateOutlet-directive.html

Comment: Ty, will try it. The context definition confuses me a bit but with the documentation I will get it. Will later accept your answer.

Comment: You can pass an object as context to be used within the template. `$implicit` is assigned if you just declare a variable like `let-items`. Properties with other names need explicit assignment like `let-idx="index"`. This way you can use the values from the context object within the template as `item` and `idx` like `<div *ngFor="let item of items">` iterates over `myData`.

Comment: Works like a charm and I understood it, ty.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is already answered, but there is another way.

create a component lets say `app-component` with the below template :

```
<ng-template>
 Same content, many divs, many ngFor..
</ng-template>
```

create a common directive lets say `masterDirective` which can conditionally apply other directives
to the element,

then configure like this

> <app-component [masterdirective]="i+1">